# When using the polymorph spell is the new shape always centred on the targets old shape?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Normally, you would assume that a character changing from a medium sized character to a Huge character using polymorph would do so as shown in example A, filling the empty squares.

[image: polymorph question]

Is example B a legitimate outcome from the spell, once again filling the empty squares?

Comment: The character in question wanted to avoid additional Attacks of Opportunity, and there was sufficient space to fit option B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the character to go from the corner (or side) to the center is covered by the 5 foot step.  I would imagine that if a character was caught in the corner of a room and polymorphs, s/he would grow to fill the square s/he is in.  Then grow out from there.  S/he would need to shift their weight while growing into that corner that doesn't budge.

Comment: they should do the 5 foot step first, and then cast polymorph.

Answer (score 3):

By not using the center of the player as the place you enlarge or shrink from, you are not only allowing the ability of the spell, but you are also allowing extra movement in that round.

From reading the polymorph spell, I do not believe it is the authors intention of giving the player any extra movement.

But I can understand the DM allowing either type. It just seems easier and more logical to enlarge or shrink from the center of the player. Otherwise you could be complicating things when there is no need to.

Comment: I agree -- there are issues of *reach* as well as movement that get brought into play when you don't grow/shrink around the centre of a creature's current size. I'd rule that growth/shrinking can only occur around a creature's centre square.

Comment: What if you go from a Large creature to a Medium creature? Which square of a Large creature's space is the "center" (2x2)?

Comment: @Strange In the case of large to medium, you can select any of the 4 squares to shrink into. And there would be no problems with giving the player any extra movement advantage.

Comment: PHBII p96 says "If the new form’s size is different from the target’s normal size, its new space must share as much of the original form’s space as possible, squeezing into the available space if necessary." I'd say both A & B do that.  Is there anywhere in the rules that say it has to be around the center square?